# Как в плагине Pods WordPress сделать таблицу?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как в плагине можно реализовать поле, позволяющее вводить данные в виде таблицы. Я нашел в типах полей списки, но они все заполняются заранее. Тоесть пользователь не может создать новую запись.

Comment: В этом плагине нельзя "создать таблицу" (что бы это ни значило). Плагин создаёт кастомные типа контента и поля.